# Flume simulation for hydraulic jump possible?

Tags: fluid-dynamics

I'm currently trying to write a high school physics paper on hydraulic jumps, I'll be investigating the effect of the slope and length of a source channel on the height of a hydraulic jump, now I won't be able to conduct the actual experiments until august, so is there any way where I'll be able to simulate the experiment on a computer using a cfd or something? Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What packages have you found? Or perhaps that should be what package(s) do youhave access to?

Comment: I've managed to get the student version for ANSYS, so I have both CFX and fluent.